# Regex to join numbers when they have spaces between them

Tags: php, python, regex, replace, preg-replace

I'm trying to build a regex that joins numbers in a string when they have spaces between them, ex:

```
$string = "I want to go home 8890 7463 and then go to 58639 6312 the cinema"
```

The regex should output:

```
"I want to go home 88907463 and then go to 586396312 the cinema"
```

The regex can be either in python or php language.

Thanks!

Comment: `"(\d) (\d)"`, then sub with `"\1\2"` ? (With Python style regexes, anyway)

Comment: @Thomas, no, would not work for `1 2 3`, you need to use at least one lookaround for such cases.

Comment: @tugaPT, what about strings like `foo123 5bar`, should those be joined too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a look-ahead to see if the next block is a set of numbers and remove the trailing space.  That way, it works for any number of sets (which I suspected you might want):

```
$string = "I want to go home 8890 7463 41234 and then go to 58639 6312 the cinema";

$newstring = preg_replace("/\b(\d+)\s+(?=\d+\b)/", "$1", $string);
// Note: Remove the \b on both sides if you want any words with a number combined.
// The \b tokens ensure that only blocks with only numbers are merged.

echo $newstring;
// I want to go home 8890746341234 and then go to 586396312 the cinema
```

Comment: I'd use something more like `/(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)/`, replaced with an empty string.

Comment: @Qtax that's a good suggestion on the variable space, however, I noticed that if I wanted to only combine blocks that are *only* numbers, I needed `\b` on both ends.  That means that you can't use look-behind, since look-behinds must use fixed width.  If that requirement isn't needed, your suggestion is a good one.

Comment: Are the `\b` tokens necessary?  Seems like `/(\d)\s+(?=\d)/` would work just as well in your regex.

Comment: @Benjam - see the note below the replacement.  What you have is what I originally had, but that meant that blocks with both numbers and letters would be merged.  I added the `\b` and the note in case the asker cares about that condition.

Comment: @Renesis - yeah, I noticed that not long after I posted that comment.  But thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3):

Python:

```
import re
text = 'abc 123 456 789 xyz'
text = re.sub(r'(\d+)\s+(?=\d)', r'\1', text)  # abc 123456789 xyz
```

This works for any number of consecutive number groups, with any amount of spacing in-between.

Comment: I'm getting syntax error for:  output = re.sub(r'(\d+)\s+(?=\d)', r'\1', output)

Comment: File "stack04.py", line 35
    result = re.sub(r'(\d+)\s+(?=\d)', r'\1', outp)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I've already solved my problem with Renesis answer but the error output is : http://pastebin.com/0p8RBTWZ, thanks anyway.

Comment: @tugaPT: I saw you accepted an answer, but I wanted to satisfy my curiosity as to why you were getting an error (I don't on my machine) ;-) It looks like it could be an indentation problem (i.e. mixing spaces with tabs). Not sure what else it could be.

Comment: it seems that python is very sensitive to spaces, after double check the code and remove some extra spaces it worked, Thank you !